# What's the best way to move a large amount data from local to azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a directory contains 65 GB files, and i try to upload files using azure storage client ,but it seems too slow, i saw there's a function Import/Export provide by azure blob storage, is there anybody knows how fast it will take to transfer 65 GB data to blob storage? 
And what's the best way to move big data from local to azure blob storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature Import / Export for Azure Storage is actually a "disk shipping" service. A real, hardware disk shipping service. Via supported shipping company and only with supported HDD vendors and specially prepared Hard Drives. This service is not intended for volumes of 65 G. More like 65 TB of data.

For large volumes of data you have several options.

You can directly use [AzCopy to transfer entire local directories to Azure Storage](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/).

If this is still slow, you can optimize the process a bit:

- Archive your folder and split in volumes (say 10 GB volumes)
- Upload each volume in parallel using [AzCopy](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/) to upload these volumes to the Storage.
- Create a VM and RDP into it
- Download the volumes locally and unarchive
- Use the [AzCopy](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/) to transfer raw files and/or folder to Azure Stroage

Comment: Azure Data Factory allows a Compression Type option for source data files that includes compression types: .zip, .tar, .tar.gz, bz2, .gz, .tar, snappy, and .lz4.  I'm fairly certain you could read a compressed file as a source and send the contents to a target container.  That could eliminate the VM requirement, and it can operate automatically via a Data Factory storage trigger.